# How to stop formatting php code in .html file using vscode

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, format

I'm using vscode to code view file in a PHP project. A traditional way is echo variables in HTML view file, javascript code block, using `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = <?php echo $i; ?>;
</script>
```

This is what I want, but the vscode keep formatting the code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = < ? php echo $i; ? >;
</script>
```

My vscode format setting is:

```
  "beautify.language": {
    "html": ["htm", "html", "php", "erb"],
    "css": ["css"],
    "js": []
  },
  "beautify.config": {
    "indent_char": " ",
    "max_preserve_newlines": 1,
    "html": {
      "indent_size": 4,
      "unformatted": ["span", "label", "a"],
      "wrap_line_length": 0
    },
    "js": {
      "indent_size": 4,
      "wrap_line_length": 0
    },
    "css": {
      "indent_size": 2
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following setting:

```
"beautify.language": {
    "html": ["htm", "html", "erb"],
    "css": ["css"],
    "js": []
  },
  "beautify.config": {
    "indent_char": " ",
    "max_preserve_newlines": 1,
    "html": {
      "indent_size": 4,
      "unformatted": ["span", "label", "a"],
      "wrap_line_length": 0
    },
    "js": {
      "indent_size": 4,
      "wrap_line_length": 0
    },
    "css": {
      "indent_size": 2
    }
  },
```